# Can I denote derivative of $f(g(x))$ in terms of $g(x)$ by $f'(g(x))_{g(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

> How to denote derivative of $f(g(x))$ in terms of $g(x)$ in prime (with $'$ without $\text{d}$) notation?

Is it conventional to denote derivative of, say, $\sin(\cos x)$ in terms of $\cos x$ in the following way:  $$\sin'(\cos x)_{\cos x}?$$

This notation is useful for using chain rule:  $$f'(g(x))=f'(g(x))_{g(x)}g'(x)$$

Edit: Please explain your downvote. If it is nonsensical to denote it this way, then at least say so in the comments.

Edit2: I've posted a [follow-up question on differentiation notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203598/a-few-questions-about-derivative-notation).

Comment: I usually use $(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Comment: I think it might be useful to give an example of a notation you've seen that made you think of this question. I suspect that your question has been misunderstood, and a little more background might help clear that up.

Comment: @DavidK My problem was that I thought that $f'(g(x))=(f\circ g)'(x)$.

Comment: Haha I just confused with the notation yesterday night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
\begin{align*}
(f\circ g)(x)=f\big(g(x)\big)
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
(f\circ g)'(x)=f'\big(g(x)\big)g'(x)
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(y)g'(x)\qquad\text{where}\qquad y=g(x).
\end{align*}
The expression
\begin{align*}
f'\big(g(x)\big)
\end{align*}
means the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $g(x)$, *not* the derivative of the function composition $f\big(g(x)\big)$ evaluated at $x$.

Comment: Indeed I thought that $f'(g(x))=(f\circ g)'(x)$.

Comment: @user89167 Nope, $f'(g(x)) = (f'\circ g)(x)$ The chain rule using Newton's dash notation, and function composition, is: $$\begin{align}(f\circ g)'(x) & = (g'\cdot f'\circ g)(x)\\[2ex] \frac{\mathrm d f(g(x))}{\mathrm d x} & = \frac{\mathrm d g(x)}{\mathrm d x}\frac{\mathrm d f(g(x))}{\mathrm d g(x)}\end{align}$$

Comment: How do I denote derivative of $f(g(x))$ in terms of $g(x)$ at point $a$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks. But [Wikipedia page for notation for differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton.27s_notation) does not find anything when I search 'dash'.

Comment: My apologies. That should have been "Lagrange's Prime notation".   Newton used the "dot" notation.