# A few questions about derivative notation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

$1)$ How do I denote derivative of $ax^2+b$ in terms of $ax^2$?

$(ax^2+b)'(ax^2)$ can easily be confused with $ax^2\cdot(ax^2+b)'$.

$2)$ How do I denote the derivative of $ax^2+b$ in terms of $ax^2$ at point $c$?

$3)$ How do I denote the derivative of $ax^2+b$ in terms of $x$ at point $c$?

$3)$ How do I denote the derivative of $f(g(x))$ in terms of $g(x)$ at point $a$?

I want to denote all of this without using $\text{d}$.

Comment: Are you talking about applications of the chain rule? I'm not sure what you mean by "in terms of".

Comment: @GFauxPas Yes. If $ax^2+b$ is a function of $ax^2$, then I'm searching how to denote its derivative.

Comment: By "in term of $ax^2$" you mean "with respect to the variable $ax^2$"?

Comment: @DouglasFinamore If $f(x)=ax^2+b$ and $g(x)=ax^2$, then I'm searching how to denote $f'(g(x))$ without using $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "with respect to $x^2$"? Saying "with respect to $ax^2$" is unusual, if $a$ is a constant.

Comment: Well, since $ax^2$ is a function, you should use the usual notation for compositions.

Comment: @GFauxPas We would have $f'(g(x))=1$. As unusual as it may seem, I've just created $2$ random functions and I'm searching for how to denote the derivative of one in terms of another. It is not nonsensical to do so.

Comment: @DouglasFinamore It is simple if I create notations for the functions $f$ and $g$ as I did in the above comment, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do so without creating the notations for new functions $f$ and $g$. It is not unusual from my experience to denote derivative of $ax^2+b$ in terms of $x$ by $(ax^2+b)'$, so a natural follow-up question is if I can do so if I want to find the derivative in terms of $ax^2$ instead of $x$.

Comment: If I understand it right, you are not using the chain rule, so $f' = 2ax$. In this case, I would write $[2ax]\left(ax^2\right)$ or $(2ax) \circ (ax^2)$.

Comment: Now, if you want to derivate it in terms of the new variable $y = ax^2$, then you have to use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)  How do I denote derivative of $ax^2 +b$  in terms of $ax^2$  ?
>
> $(ax^2 +b) ′ (ax^2 )$  can easily be confused with $ax^2 \cdot (ax^2 +b) ′$  .

Ah.  Where as the prime notation on a function symbol is taken as being with respect to *the function's argument*, the prime notation over an *expression* is taken as being with respect to the *independent variable* of the discussion (most *usually* that is either $x$ or $t$).

That is, if $f(x)=ax+b$, then $\;f'(ax^2) = \frac{\mathrm d f(ax^2)}{\mathrm d (ax^2)} = \frac{\mathrm d (ax^2+b)}{\mathrm d (ax^2)} \\[2ex] f(ax^2)' = (ax^2+b)' = \frac{\mathrm d (ax^2+b)}{\mathrm d x}$

So, you want to use the prime notation on an expression to indicate you are deriving with respect to another expression rather than the implicit variable itself.

$$[u\mapsto u+b]' (ax^2) = \left.\frac{\mathrm d u+b}{\mathrm d u}\right\vert_{u:=ax^2} = \frac{\mathrm d(ax^2+b)}{\mathrm d (ax^2)}$$

---

You could establish in your forward that you were using a subscripted dash notation.

$$(ax^2+b)'_{(ax^2)} = \frac{\mathrm d (ax^2+b)}{\mathrm d (ax^2)}$$

---

Or simply rely on the chain rule.  $\frac{\mathrm d (ax^2+b)}{\mathrm d x}\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d (ax^2)} = \frac{(ax^2+b)'}{(ax^2)'}$

Comment: Your idea seems to be to simply replace $f$ with $[x\to x+b]$, which is sort of cheating.